# Which part of my idea is wrong about infinite energy produced by EMF for certain circumstance?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

As a someone who is on the first year of EEE student,

facts in a simple way:

- time varying magnetic fields around conductors produce electricity
- for outer space, object will keep going at the same speed and in the same direction as long as zero net force on it

So, what if I set a circuit like, huge magnet on/in space and huge rotor(conductor) keep circulating at same speed within the magnetic field due to zero force on it ?(may need a initial speed with the help of,a rocket might be)

Of course I might get wrong with many concepts, so could you tell me about it?

Comment: but what about the *magnetic force*?

Comment: The random variation of the magnetic fields would be unpredictable and wouldn't result in any net gain of potential energy over useful timescales.

Comment: As you know, there is a huge energy will be produced by it. Wouldn't it tolareted with many simple rockets on the rotor ? I mean, the energy to keep stable the whole system is much much less then to energy produced by the systems' itself?

Answer (score 2):

I assume the "infinite energy" you're wondering about is electrical energy from current induced in the huge circulating rotor.  As soon as you get an induced current there will be an induced magnetic field that will interact with the huge magnet and oppose the motion of the coil.  Ask [Heinrich Lenz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz%27s_law) all about it.

Answer (score 0):

The essence of what you described lies in Maxwell/Faraday's equation:

$$ \nabla\times\vec E = -\frac{\partial \vec B}{\partial t} $$

Which indeed implies that an electromotive force is induced in a time-varying magnetic field. This induced current follows [Lenz's law](http://www.britannica.com/science/Lenzs-law), which states that the current generates a magnetic field that *opposes* the change that caused it.

So think of it by analyzing this diagram:

[image: EMF]

Source: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/imgele/lenz.gif

A current can be classically thought of as electrons (or protons) moving through a circuit, so moving charges produce magnetic fields, right? Just think of the direction in which the magnetic field is produced and the conservation of energy should pop right out from your analysis!

Comment: Now, I understood what you all are telling me. Thanks. @mustang